# replacing a term in vector using str_replace_all function R

Tags: r, vector, replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace the hyphen `-` in a vector with a period `.`.

```
> samples_149_vector 
$Patient.ID
  [1] MB-0020 MB-0100 MB-0115 MB-0158 MB-0164 MB-0174 MB-0179 MB-0206
  [9] MB-0214 MB-0238 MB-0259 MB-0269 MB-0278 MB-0333 MB-0347 MB-0352
 [17] MB-0372 MB-0396 MB-0399 MB-0400 MB-0401 MB-0420 MB-0424 MB-0446
 [25] MB-0464 MB-0476 MB-0481 MB-0489 MB-0494 MB-0495 MB-0500 MB-0502
```

The following code

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(samples_149_vector, "-", ".")
```

generates the following error:

```
> str_replace_all(samples_149_vector, "-", ".")
[1] "1:149"                                                           
[2] "function (length = 0) \n.Internal(vector(\"character\", length))"
Warning message:
In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

Any ideas? I have tried so many things and combinations but the coercing atomic vector message seems to reoccur

Comment: What type of object is `samples_149_vector`?

Comment: You need to `escape` ie `\\.` or use character classes although I can't reproduce. Could you add data with `dput`?

Comment: @NelsonGon, could you perhaps clarify this with reference to my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add data to your question with `dput(df)` so we're working with the same data. Please edit to add data in that format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try utilizing an escape since `"."` is used to match any character when matching patterns with regular expressions? To create the regular expression, you need to use `"\\."`

```
str_replace_all(samples_149_vector, "-", "\\.")
```

Comment: Replacements are taken literally--unless you're using capturing groups you don't need to escape special characters, e.g., `stringr::str_replace_all("a---s-s-s-a", "-", ".")` works fine. (Matching `.` in the `pattern`, of course, would require escaping as you've shown.) Which means the problem is probably OP's input data structure.